# How to put the values of a 1D array into a 2D array in C++ using for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

I want to put the values for a 1 D array into a 2D array. Then I want to print out the values of the 2D array.

I have the following code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>          //for _kbhit
using namespace std;
#define MAX_N 100

#include<stdio.h>

int c[MAX_N] = {35, 23 , 56 , 30, 110 , 123 , 13 , 31 };

int b[4][4];
int main()
{

    int i,j,k,l;
    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    { cout << c[i];}
    cout << endl;

    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {   for(j=0;j<4;j++)
         {
          b[i][j] = c[i];
         }
    }
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<4;j++)
                {
                    cout << b[i][j] << " ";
                }
        cout << "\n";   
        cout << "\n";
        }
cout << "\n\nHit<enter> to finish";
while ( !_kbhit());
return (0);
}
```

The output should be:

```
35 23 56 30
110 123 13 31
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd start by doing some *math*. You're output loop has sixteen overall writes. If you expect only *eight* items, your math is obviously wrong.

Comment: From `b[i][j] = c[i];` it's clear that all `b[i][x]` would have the same value, for any `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let original array be

```
int arr[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60};
```

you opt for number of rows that you want so that you can divide your array in to 2 dimensions accordingly.

```
int row;
cout << "Enter Number of rows: ";
cin >> row;
```

after that initialize your 2D array like by calculating the number of columns via

```
int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
int col = (int) ceil(size/row); // from math.h/cmath library
int array[row][col];
```

now iterate over and fill the 2D Array using the 1D array

```
int idx = 0;
for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<col && idx<size; j++) 
        array[i][j] = arr[idx++];
```

**Dry run**

```
arr = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

Enter Number of rows = 2

array = {{10, 20, 30},
         {40, 50, 60}}
```

Edit: `idx<size` in the inner-nested loop of the filling 2D array with 1D array. This way you can handle odd number sized 1D array.

Comment: So, apparently this works, thanks! I had to add the: int idx = 0; can you please elaborate a bit? How that works? Any comments would be useful.

Comment: Np just try to draw out your problem on a copy that way you'd learn more about the insights of the problem and just tick the answer that helped the most so that others realize that this task has been completed and people won't check this link. Glad I could be of help :) @AlPap

Comment: ```array[i][j] = arr[idx++];``` with ```i=0``` ```j=0``` and ```idx=0``` shows that everyone is pointing at the start of the index, ```array[0][0] = arr[0] // 10```, after that ```idx++``` increments the value of ```idx``` by 1, and this keeps happening until the array is completely filled. Therefore ```array[0][0] = arr[0] //10```, ```array[1][0] = arr[1] //20```, ```array[0][1] = arr[2] //30``` ... ```array[2][2] = arr[5] //10```

Answer (score 0):

If c would have 16 elements:

```
for(int i = 0, row = 0; row < 4; ++row)
{
    for(int column = 0; column < 4; ++i, ++column)
    {
        b[row][column] = c[i];
    }
}
```